# Custom Module Route returns 404

Tags: magento2

Any reason why my custom module's route would work on local, but not in production? I've nuked caches, upgraded, compiled, etc. Is there something I'm not considering?

routes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
 <router id="standard">
    <route id="seeinstore" frontName="seeinstore">
      <module name="Ibex_Seeinstore" />
    </route>
 </router>
</config>
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ibex_Seeinstore" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

registration.php:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ibex_Seeinstore',
    __DIR__
);
```

Ibex/SeeInStore/Controller/Index/Index.php:

```
namespace Ibex\Seeinstore\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**New info:** In my nginx error log, this is the only error that seems potentially relevant:

```
464045 access forbidden by rule, client: [redacted], server: [redacted], request: "POST /app/etc/config.php HTTP/1.1", host: [redacted]
```

Still totally bewildered by this -- any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check logs?

Comment: @kunj Which log would I check for this?

Comment: Magento logs  `{{root path of Magento}}/var/log/`

Comment: Yeah, but which one? I see nothing in exception or system

Comment: can you share  that files?

Comment: Or please share your module file structure and file contents.

Comment: The log files? I'm confident that nothing in that particular folder right now is relevant. Because everything is working locally, I'm thinking there's nothing wrong with the codebase but maybe there's a permissions issue, etc?

Comment: Ok, then please check your module exist in `{{root path of Magento }}/app/etc/config.php`.

Comment: Also, check those files accessible to root user of that server?

Comment: Confirmed that the module exists in config.php

Comment: Remove generated and cache folders manually then try.

Comment: Cleared 'em, no change. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: can you share your code? Like `module.xml`, `routes.xml`

Comment: Hi @kunj I've edited my post with this code, thanks

Comment: @Brockfast Cowboy 
Have you created registration.php file in your module?

Comment: @RonakParmar of course, I'll include it as well

Comment: Have you checked server root user have permission to edit those files?

Comment: I have just shared a link, you can refer that link as well to compare your module. hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi @kunj -- I'm fuzzy on how permissions affect things, I think that's likely the issue. The files of the module are `-rw-rw-r-- ` and the folders are `drwxrwxr-x` --should this change?

Comment: Sometime if you upload any file from other user to server that time root user can not edit/update those file and folders. Even that files can not run. Recently one persion has faced same issue.

Comment: That's helpful, @kunj -- do you know how this can be resolved?

Comment: I am sure, that `routes.xml` file in `app/code/Ibex/Seeinstore/etc/frontend/`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77621/discussion-on-question-by-brockfast-cowboy-custom-module-route-returns-404).

Answer (score 1):

If your server is running on LAMP, check your virtual host to find the log path like that:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo nano domainame.com.conf
```

You will get something like this:

[image: virtual-host]
In this case, to see the error log i have to:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Once you do that try t access again your page, if there's any module missing or php error it will get prompted.
Probably the problem you're facing is related to the environment and not the module itself. If you're on a Lemp stack see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706111/where-can-i-find-the-error-logs-of-nginx-using-fastcgi-and-django

Comment: Thanks @arjus ! This helped me find my error log. I'll edit my post with the error that might be relevant.

Comment: Hi @BrockfastCowboy i'm happy it worked! Edit your question when you can and please mark my answer as correct (the green check image). Best!

Comment: Hi @arjus -- your answer didn't help me with my issue, but it helped me find the log so I've upvoted it but haven't marked it as correct. Y'know?

Comment: @BrockfastCowboy ok, I thought you reached the error and solve the problem through the log. thanks for the upvote. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chown -R user {{Your extension folder path}}
```

This command will change the user and group at the same time:

```
chown user:group {{Your extension folder path}}
```

Comment: What user/group should I be changing to? Root? Right now all folders/files are owned by the website user

Comment: I can't suggest you without check, I would suggest you to ask that server management user.